# Signing key for RabbitMQ

Tags: error-handling, rabbitmq, erlang, epel

For the process of installation of RabbitMQ on CentOS7, I followed the process as mentioned in the below link. https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/fe34e83781f222dfd8533b36a52dddcc . I started with installing EPEL, Erlang (necessity for RabbitMQ). But I am facing an error in the installation after running the command:

```
sudo rpm --import https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc
```

The error is as follows:

```
warning: rabbitmq-server-3.8.35-1.el8.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 6026dfca: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    erlang >= 23.2 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.8.35-1.el8.noarch
```

I have a question on the signing key requirement.

- Is there a need for signing key while installing RabbitMQ?
- If yes,how should a new user go forward with it?
- Given to it, please do also let me know if I am missing out on any additional steps/requirements for the installation process.

Comment: update on the error: since it was an Erlang version, the Rabbitmq was installed properly after the Erlang version 24 was installed. But there is a new error of the RabbitMQ server not initiating. What are the exact commands when starting the RabbitMQ process on CentOS 7?